# Global Lipschitzity of a truncated Nemytskii operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a locally Lipschitz continuous function. Meaning that:
$$
\forall M>0,\quad \exists L_M>0, \quad \max\{{x},{y}\}\leq M \Longrightarrow \vert f(x)-f(y)\vert \leq L_M \vert x-y\vert.
$$
Consider the following mollifier
$$
\forall x\geq 0, \forall k>0,\quad \eta_k(x)=\begin{cases}1\quad \text{if}\quad x\leq k; \\
0\quad \text{if}\quad x \geq 2k.
 \end{cases}
$$
Then the Nemytskii operator
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F: &L^2(\Omega) \longrightarrow L^2(\Omega)\\
&u\mapsto F(\eta_k(\Vert u \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}) u)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open set with regular boundary,
and
$$
F(u)(x)=f(u(x)), \quad \forall x\in \Omega.
$$
A published article states that the operator $F$ is globally Lipschitz?

However, I have tried to distinguish the cases. For the first case, I let $k>0,$ then
$$\max\{\Vert u \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)},\Vert v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}\} \leq k \Longrightarrow
\Vert F(u)-F(v) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2=\int_\Omega \vert f(u(x))-f(v(x))\vert^2 dx.$$
I can't estimate the right hand side by using just the Local Lipschitzity of $f$ since I don't have $$ \max \{ \vert u (x) \vert,\vert v(x) \vert\} \leq k.$$

Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: Maybe the truncated function is defined by $u(x) \mapsto F( \eta_k( u(x))$?

Comment: @daw Unfortunately, the author didn't define it this way. Since $u \in L^2(\Omega)$